# Triangle symbol in pneumatic diagrams

Tags: fluid, pneumatic, diagram

After searching details regarding direction control valves, I can understand that the diagonal line indicates solenoid valve actuation. The zig Zag line represents the spring action so in this case the DCV will move towards right when solenoid is powered.

Only one question arises, what is the meaning of the triangle they have mentioned in the SOV diagram?

[image]

Comment: Did you consult the legend in the source?

Comment: There was no legend given in the catalogue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a two stage actuator where the triangle represents a pilot. That means that there is a pressure assist. The direction of the arrow indicates the direction of flow.